# How do I compare JSON in a grails test

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a controller in Grails that is returning a response in JSON.

I have written a test which works roughly like this

```
test(){
     def expectedResponse=JSON.parse('[{"username":"user","startDate":"2010-11-30"}]')
    ...
            def actualResponse=JSON.parse(response.text)

            println "Expecting: ${expectedResponse.toString()}"
            println "Actual: ${actualResponse.toString()}"

            assertEquals(expectedResponse.toString(), actualResponse.toString())
    ...
        }
```

This works as expected

```
Expecting: [{"username":"user","startDate":"2010-11-30"}]
Actual: [{"username":"user","startDate":"2010-11-30"}]
```

However, I was wondering if there was a better way to do this without resorting to a string comparison.. Perhaps something that could leave me the flexibility to be able to add attributes to the response without invalidating my test case?

I could build this myself, but I would've expected some sort of JSON comparison to be built into the language.

Update:
I tried doing this directly, without the toString and have had inconsistent results, not quite sure why, it was working at one stage then suddenly got this. I can't see any code changes I made that would've caused the difference

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.siggysale.MainControllerTests.assertEquals() is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONArray, org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONArray) values: [[], []]
```

Comment: Thinking this over again, I think a string comparison is probably a good approach for the most part

Comment: You should just be able to compare `expectedResponse` and `actualResponse`, no?

Comment: @tim_yates very odd, first time I tried that, it didn't work, seemed to be complaining about being unable to assertEquals two arrays (from memory)... Now I've just tried it again taking away the toString() component in that sample and it worked... no idea what happened the first time

Comment: Ok scratch that it's happening again, I get this when doing the direct comparison i.e. assertEquals(expectedResponse, actualResponse)
No signature of method: com.myproj.MainControllerTests.assertEquals() is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONArray, org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONArray)

Comment: can't you `assert expectedResponse == actualResponse`

Comment: hrmm.. ok I just tried assertTrue(expectedResponse == actualResponse) and it worked, but I also tried testing using assertEquals(expectedResponse, actualResponse) and that worked this time around... I'm getting very inconsistent results with this I handn't changed those tests otherwise so I really can't explain it

Comment: yuck there must be some sort of bug in my compiler, for a different test.. just got this message
No signature of method: com.myproj.MainControllerTests.assertEquals() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer) values: [10, 0], made a minor whitespace change and then saved&compiled and it went away

Answer (score 5):

You can compare json using [GJSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) libraray using the code below.

```
class GJsonUtil {

    static Boolean compareJsonStrings(String obj1, String obj2){
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        JsonElement o1 = parser.parse(obj1)
        JsonElement o2 = parser.parse(obj2)
        return o1==o2
    }
}
```

This is also tested using few test cases. As you can see order of element in a json doesn't matter i.e. {test1:1,test2:2} should be same as {test2:2,test1:1}.

```
class GJsonSpec extends UnitSpec {

    @Unroll("#ID : comparing two json")
    def "Comparing json string"() {

        setup:

        when:
        def json1String = (obj1 as JSON).toString()
        def json2String = (obj2 as JSON).toString()
        println "json1String=${json1String}"
        println "json2String=${json2String}"
        def match=GJsonUtil.compareJsonStrings(json1String,json2String)

        then:
             match==result

        where:

        ID | obj1                    | obj2                    | result
        1  | [a: 1, b: [c: 1, d: 2]] | [b: [c: 1, d: 2], a: 1] | true
        2  | [a: 1, b: [c: 1, d: 3]] | [b: [c: 1, d: 2], a: 1] | false
        3  | [a: 2, b: [c: 1, d: 2]] | [b: [c: 1, d: 2], a: 1] | false
        4  | [a: 1, b: [d: 1, c: 2]] | [b: [d: 1, c: 2], a: 1] | true
        5  | [a: 1, b: [d: [x:"ram",y:"Laxman"], c: 2]] | [b: [d: [x:"ram",y:"Laxman"], c: 2], a: 1] | true//deep json comparision
        6  | [a: 1, b: [d: [x:"Ram",y:"Laxman"], c: 2]] | [b: [d: [x:"ram",y:"laxman"], c: 2], a: 1] | false//deep json comparision+ lower/uppercase
        7  | [a: 1, b: [d: [x:"Ram",y:["test1","test2","test3"]], c: 2]] | [b: [d: [x:"Ram",y:["test1","test3","test2"]], c: 2], a: 1] | false//deep json comparision+ lower/uppercase
        8  | [a: ["test1","test2","test3"]] | [a:["test1","test2","test3"] ] | true//comaparing list order
        9  | [a: ["test1","test2","test3"]] | [a:["test1","test3","test2"] ] | false//comaparing list order should fail
        10|[:]|null|false
        11|null|[:]|false
        12|null|null|true
        13|[a: ["test1",null,"test3"]] | [a:["test1",null,"test3"] ] | true//comaparing nulls in json



    }


}
```

Hope that helps!!!
Thanks,

Anuj Aneja

Answer (score 1):

How about comparing JSON values?

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def test() {
    def obj = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response.text)

    assert obj[0].username == "user"
    assert obj[0].startDate == "2010-11-30"

    // make sure there isn't any other data
    assert obj.size() == 1
    assert obj[0].size() == 2
}
```

(you have to use `obj[0]` instead of `obj` because you are returning a JSON array with 1 element)

Comment: hi micha, yes I considered this, but I thought it better to have a string version of my expected JSON in the test to compare it to, just to be clear visually if nothing else

Comment: The problem with strings is that your test might fail, even if the response of your controller is valid. What if the order of the properties changes and `startDate` is returned before `username`? In addition to that it becomes very annoying if the controller returns larger amounts of json and you want to validate only certain parts of the response. You are also not able to tell which field caused to problem, you always have to look at the complete json string to find the bug if a test fails.

Comment: yes I totally agree with you there.. I really need something in the middle, compare this expected JSON string with this JSON response, but ignore additional attributes and ordering.. I've seen a similar sort of groovy syntax done with maps so I was wondering if it was possible with JSON

Comment: When talking groovy, this should be the accepted answer. No need for external libraries because comparing results of `JsonSlurper` does exactly the same!

Answer (score 1):

I use `org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.JSONAssert`. Is at simple as:

```
JSONAssert.assertEquals(expectedJson, json, true)
```